# curious to know how to use ISuite

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I was working on selenium using java programming language and came to know about ISuite. I am curious to know about ISuite why or when is it used in testNG. I want to know how to use it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. This question as it is currently written is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There are several interfaces that allow you to modify TestNG's behavior. These interfaces are broadly called "TestNG Listeners". `ISuiteListener` is one of them.

Try creating a `ISuiteListener` as follows (any TestNG listener should work):

```
package test.tmp;
public class TmpSuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {
  @Override
  public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
    System.out.println("Finishing");
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    System.out.println("Starting");
  }
}
```

For more documentation you can refer [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

Let me know if this Answers your Question.